# Estimating a sample mean using sub-sample means

Tags: statistics, average, estimation

we collect a lot of data on a daily basis via an API, and part of this data includes fields that represent sample means. Specifically, we get provided with a sample mean and the sample size, lets call them `avg_pos` and `impressions`. If you can't tell yet, the domain is advertising, `avg_pos` tells us the average position our ad showed in over the period of a day, and `impressions` tells us how many impressions we got (the size of the sample used for `avg_pos`).

Now, suppose I want to get the average position for a 30 day period — we only have available to us 30 `avg_pos` values and 30 `impressions` values. The sum of `impressions` is the amount of impressions over the entire period.

Question: intuitively I think one way to estimate the 30 day average position would be to do something like:

$$
total\_impressions = \sum impressions
\\
\sum avg\_pos * \frac{impressions}{total\_impressions}
$$

Can someone explain the implications of this approach, and when it is likely to be accurate and when it is not? I assume its accuracy will depend on how normally distributed all the position values are that make up the `avg_pos` sample means.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula is exactly right and completely accurate (up to rounding error). If I get some number of observations each day, I will get exactly the same answer whether I wait to the end of the month and then average them all, or average them each day and then calculate a weighted average of my daily averages at the end of the month, which is what you're doing. This is because of [linearity of expectations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity).